# How to override twitter bootstrap color in all the elements?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using `twitter-bootstrap-3` and I would like in all places where these default color [#428bca](http://www.colorhexa.com/428bca) override it to some other.

[image]

I wouldn't make it manually in CSS for each component I need, I would rather not go also for generation of customized bootstrap version, I would like make this change in one place, so that if I change my mind for some other color it is extremly fast to change.

I consider even brutforce replace all `#428bca` to my color. Will it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find and replacing all the color codes would work. If you want to change a variable once and the changes to propagate through all the CSS rules you should look into SASS or LESS.

Comment: could you please demonstrate how to do such replacment in SASS

Comment: Here's more info on Bootstrap with LESS http://bootstrap.lesscss.ru/less.html  and SASS http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/bootstrap-and-sass/ ... you'll have to learn the basics of SASS or LESS. They are not hard to learn...but you will need some new tools in your belt :). I recommend taking a look at http://yeoman.io/ also ... if you're into front end stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you are using `less` or `sass` you could overwrite the color just once in there. Otherwise, I can't think of any other method.

However, if you are not using `less` or `sass`, you can customize the entire bootstrap before downloading it:

http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#colors